# Pulp action paperback, alien living "net"

Tags: story-identification

On a trip to the cottage as a kid I read a pulp sci-fi I picked up somewhere. This would be in the 1975 to 1978 era, although the book itself could be from any period before then. It was quite small, perhaps 100 pages? It had a few illustrations so I assume it was written for the tween market. Even though I was around 10 I knew it wasn't Tristram Shandy, but nostalgia being what it is...

The story was about a sort of detective-for-hire and I think there was something about slaves. It had a sort of *Stainless Steel Rat* feel to the story arc but was not nearly as clever in either the prose or the action (it's almost certainly not a Harrison book).

The one scene I distinctly remember takes place about 1/3rd of the way into the action when he was working undercover on a space ship. He realizes they have figured him out and gets called to the bridge. He goes anyway, hoping to brazen his way out.

He arrives and notices no one seems particularly worried about his presence, which sets off his alarm bells. At that point a sort of living net drops on him from the ceiling and nearly squeezes him to death, but he breaks free. This was one of the few illustrations. When he kills the monster using his fingernails and biting, they pull guns on him.

Comment: Read in the US? UK?

Comment: Ahh, Canada. So likely US, but no guarantee.

Comment: I wonder if this is one of the Perry Rhodan books? Although, I have to admit i don't remember those every having illustrations in them.

Comment: Well now I have something else I have to read, especially the one "mit poster"! But given the timing I read in the Wiki article it sounds like this would have still been in the adventure phase, as opposed to "hard boiled". This was more "undercover cop in space".